# Refresh tableview on UIAlert event

Tags: objective-c

I am loading a tableview. And on an event, an alertview will appear. After I cancel the alert view, I need to change the value in a cell in the table(refresh table). I am not able to access tableview from inside the alertview event. Help needed.

Comment: Did you try `[self.tableview reloadData];`?

Comment: check out all the responses.. but i think for ur state, Narayana's answer would be most helping.. **checkout if you are using only button..**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set delegate of your alert view to self and implement [alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:].

Answer (score 0):

After the alert is shown you can set your refresh login when the user clicks on cancel button.

for that you have to use this

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
      if (buttonIndex == 0)
      {
    //cancel clicked ...do your action
      }
        else if (buttonIndex == 1)
   {
    //reset clicked
   }
  }
```

dont forget to add the UIAlertViewDelegate in your .h file

Answer (score 0):

This is a use for the delegate pattern. You need to set the table's view controller as the delegate of the alert view. Then the table view controller will receive the `-alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` message whenever the alert view is dismissed with a button press. From this method, you can call `-reloadData` on your table or whatever you have to do to make it update itself.

Answer (score 0):

At time of alertview allocation set delegate to self and overwrite below delegate method .In below method you can get which button you pressed in alertview

```
-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex==0)
       {
         //
       }
       else if(buttonIndex==1)
       {
         [yourTableObject reloadData];
       }
}
```